# Accessing the callback authorisation token for Instagram API

Tags: instagram-api, p5.js

Hi I'm trying to access the instagram API using p5.js to do some research using geocached images. I'm generating a call back url from Instagram but can't seem to access the url, it gives me the original url rather than the returned one. Does anyone have any suggestions to delay calling the getURL()?

```
function setup() {
  button = createButton('click me');
  button.mousePressed(getCallback);
  urlString = getURL();
}

function getCallback() {
  window.location = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token';
}
```

Apologies I'm a newbie in Stack Exchange and Javascript. This is all the code so far. Its a simple button that links to Instagram, when a user validates using their account it sends back a url to `http://localhost:3000/callback`. The url in the code above is not the actual url as I didn't want to include my instagram developers client ID. Effectively I am getting back a url something like - `http://localhost:3000/callback#access_token=8828684.53c6a46` - and need to extract the token off the end of the callback url. I have been trying to use the P5 method to getURL() but this extracts the initial url `http://localhost:3000`, rather than the one which gets sent back with the token.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? Right now this code is incomplete, so it doesn't really tell us much.